# Regular expressions -- how to allow non-adjacent alternatives?

Tags: python, regex, string

In a translation-testing app (in Python) I want a regular expression that will accept either of these two strings:

```
a = "I want the red book"
b = "the book which I want is red"
```

So far I'm using something like this:

```
^(the book which )*I want (is |the )red (book)*$
```

This will accept both string a and string b. But it will also accept a string without *either* of the two optional sub-strings:

```
sub1 = (the book which )
sub2 = (book)
```

How can I indicate that one of these two substrings must be present, even though they're not adjacent?

I realize that in this example it would be trivially easy to avoid the problem by just testing for longer alternatives separated by "or" `|`. This is a simplified example of a problem that is harder to avoid with the actual user input I'm working with.

Comment: You say that your actual problem is more complicated than the single example you've given here. IMO that makes it difficult to really answer your question.

Have you considered using something like the NLTK to do this in the most general way possible (http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch05.html) ? It might be overkill for your purposes, but again that's impossible to tell without more details in the question.

Comment: If this is a trivialised example of the problem, any solution I give to the question you have asked may not solve your *actual* problem and will therefore waste my time and yours. Please give a real example and we may be able to solve this (probably without even touching regular expressions). See also, [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56366/147331).

Comment: OK. But I thought my question was clear--is there a way to require one of two non-adjacent alternatives in regex. Rather than just telling me to give a more complex example, can you answer the question I asked? Is the "or" operator the only way to define required alternatives?

Comment: @phooji _"your actual problem is more complicated than the single example you've given here. IMO that makes it difficult to really answer your question"_ Do you realize that it means that simplifying a problem doesn't allow to solve more easily the simplified problem than the complicated one ? That means also that the level of difficulty of the simplified problem depends only on the level of difficulty of the complicated one, without taking account what kind of simplification is done (little or big).

Comment: @Johnsyweb IMHO, you are right on the point that it may be an XY problem. But "may" means perhaps; in the present case, I think it is only an hypothesis. Another hypothesis can be made: we may think that the questioner, who does things in the field of linguistics, which is a hard discipline, has enough capabilities of conceptualization and reasoning to know if a solution of the simplified problem will help him to solve the complicated one and if it is worth to solve the complicated problem. The possibility of XY problems doesn't allow to think that all simplified problems are Y.

Comment: @monotasker _"I thought my question was clear"_ It is. _"Is the "or" operator the only way to define required alternatives? "_ No, there are also conditional alternatives: see ``(?(id/name)yes-pattern|no-pattern)`` in http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#module-re

Comment: The *real* problem here is thinking that regular expressions are a good tool to use for general parsing. Now you have two problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a problem that might be better solved with a [difflib.SequenceMatcher](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-examples) than with regular expressions.

However, a regular expression that works for the specific example in the original question is as follows:

```
^(the book which )*I want (is |the )red((?(1)(?: book)*| book))$
```

This will fail for the string "I want the red" (which lacks both of the required substrings "the books which " and " book"). This uses the (?(id/name)yes-pattern|no-pattern) syntax which allows for alternatives based on the existence of a previously matched group.

Comment: Surely you don't want to allow *"the book which the book which I want..."*. so '?'s not '\*'s, but even then *"the book which I want the red..."* passes which is *also* not desired.

Comment: @dmckee. the details are unimportant - i was just trying to answer the more general question about matching non-adjacent alternatives.

Comment: The details are critically important because they show how hard it is to do this even for well defined cases much less for a irregular input language.

Comment: I made it clear in the first part of my answer that I don't think regular expressions are the best way to solve these kinds of problems. But in any case, if you read the original question carefully, the example regular expression given by questioner is only "something like" what they are really using. In other words, it's just a toy example to illustrate their real question, and so the details don't particularly matter.

Comment: Thanks @ekhumoro. I'll look into the sequence matcher you recommend. But it also helps to learn about conditional matching.

Answer (score 5):

> How can I indicate that one of these two substrings must be present,
>   even though they're not adjacent?

I am assuming that is the core question you have.

The solution is two regex's. Why people feel that once the say `import re` that the regex has to be a single line is just beyond me.

First test for the first substring in one regex, then test for the other substring with another regex. Logically combine those two results.

Comment: +1: Two regular expressions are likely to be clearer (and more... ..."expressive") than one.

Comment: Thanks @carrot-top. Strangely, I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

regx1 = re.compile('^(the book which )*I want (is |the )red'   '((?(1)|(?: book)))$')

regx2 = re.compile('^(the book which )*I want (is |the )red'   '((?(1)(?: book)*|(?: book)))$')




for x in ("I want the red book",
          "the book which I want is red",
          "I want the red",
          "the book which I want is red book"):
    print x
    print regx1.search(x).groups() if regx1.search(x) else 'No match'
    print regx2.search(x).groups() if regx2.search(x) else 'No match'
    print
```

result

```
I want the red book
(None, 'the ', ' book')
(None, 'the ', ' book')

the book which I want is red
('the book which ', 'is ', '')
('the book which ', 'is ', '')

I want the red
No match
No match

the book which I want is red book
No match
('the book which ', 'is ', ' book')
```

**edit**

Your regex pattern

```
^(the book which )*I want (is |the )red (book)*$
```

doesn't match correctly for all the sentences because of the last blank in it.

It must be

```
'^(the book which )*I want (is |the )red( book)*$'
```

Comment: The same complaints I made to ekhumoro apply here.